# Composer dependency error when installing Sylius Bundles into Symfony 2.4

Tags: php, symfony, composer-php, sylius

I have problems installing Sylius Bundles (namely SyliusProductBundle) into a fresh Symfony 2.4 install

```
rm -rf * .gitignore .travis.yml
composer create-project symfony/framework-standard-edition ./ 2.4.* --prefer-dist
```

Symfony install goes through with no errors:
    Clearing the cache for the dev environment with debug true
    Installing assets using the hard copy option
    Installing assets for Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle into web/bundles/framework
    Installing assets for Acme\DemoBundle into web/bundles/acmedemo
    Installing assets for Sensio\Bundle\DistributionBundle into web/bundles/sensiodistribution

On we go, next to installing the bundles - let's first use the way it's described in the [docs](http://docs.sylius.org/en/latest/bundles/SyliusProductBundle/installation.html) :

```
composer require "sylius/product-bundle":"1.0.*@dev"
```

fails:

```
./composer.json has been updated
Loading composer repositories with package information
Updating dependencies (including require-dev)
Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.

  Problem 1
    - Installation request for sylius/product-bundle 1.0.*@dev -> satisfiable by sylius/product-bundle[1.0.x-dev].
    - sylius/product-bundle 1.0.x-dev requires sylius/resource-bundle 1.0.*@dev -> no matching package found.

Potential causes:
 - A typo in the package name
 - The package is not available in a stable-enough version according to your minimum-stability setting
   see <https://groups.google.com/d/topic/composer-dev/_g3ASeIFlrc/discussion> for more details.

Read <http://getcomposer.org/doc/articles/troubleshooting.md> for further common problems.

Installation failed, reverting ./composer.json to its original content.
```

I've tried several things (including an install of Doctrine Bundle 1.3 which led to even more errors referring to some Class missing and thus failing to clear the cache):

```
2.2751   19015200   9. require('-ABSOLUTE PATH HERE-vendor/doctrine/doctrine-bundle/Doctrine/Bundle/DoctrineBundle/Command/Proxy/CollectionRegionDoctrineCommand.php') -ABSOLUTE PATH HERE-vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/Debug/DebugClassLoader.php:120

Script Sensio\Bundle\DistributionBundle\Composer\ScriptHandler::clearCache handling the post-update-cmd event terminated with an exception



  [RuntimeException]
  An error occurred when executing the "'cache:clear --no-warmup'" command.
```

I've read that it might be a problem with my configuration which is why I made sure that the system timezone is set correctly which it definetely is. 
My set up reads as follows:
Mac OS X 10.9
MAMP free with PHP 5.4.10, installed Extensions include XDebug and XCache
I'm out of luck on this one and would appreciate a solution.

Thanks!

As suggested, my composer.json

```
{
    "name": "symfony/framework-standard-edition",
    "license": "MIT",
    "type": "project",
    "description": "The \"Symfony Standard Edition\" distribution",
    "autoload": {
        "psr-0": { "": "src/" }
    },
    "require": {
        "php": ">=5.3.3",
        "symfony/symfony": "~2.4",
        "doctrine/orm": "~2.2,>=2.2.3",
        "doctrine/doctrine-bundle": "~1.2",
        "twig/extensions": "~1.0",
        "symfony/assetic-bundle": "~2.3",
        "symfony/swiftmailer-bundle": "~2.3",
        "symfony/monolog-bundle": "~2.4",
        "sensio/distribution-bundle": "~2.3",
        "sensio/framework-extra-bundle": "~3.0",
        "sensio/generator-bundle": "~2.3",
        "incenteev/composer-parameter-handler": "~2.0"
    },
    "scripts": {
        "post-install-cmd": [
            "Incenteev\\ParameterHandler\\ScriptHandler::buildParameters",
            "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::buildBootstrap",
            "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::clearCache",
            "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::installAssets",
            "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::installRequirementsFile"
        ],
        "post-update-cmd": [
            "Incenteev\\ParameterHandler\\ScriptHandler::buildParameters",
            "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::buildBootstrap",
            "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::clearCache",
            "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::installAssets",
            "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::installRequirementsFile"
        ]
    },
    "config": {
        "bin-dir": "bin"
    },
    "extra": {
        "symfony-app-dir": "app",
        "symfony-web-dir": "web",
        "incenteev-parameters": {
            "file": "app/config/parameters.yml"
        },
        "branch-alias": {
            "dev-master": "2.4-dev"
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: show us the composer.json

Comment: Hey, composer.json is the default for Symfony - I'll add it to the post anyway. Thank you!

Comment: Is there any specific reason you're trying to install the `@dev` version of the bundle? Do you really need anything that was added after the latest `~1.0` version ? Otherwise the solution would be quite simple ... ommit the `@dev`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to add "minimum-stability": "dev" to your composer.json

here is you composer.json with "sylius/product-bundle":"1.0.*@dev"

```
{
    "name": "symfony/framework-standard-edition",
    "license": "MIT",
    "type": "project",
    "description": "The \"Symfony Standard Edition\" distribution",
    "autoload": {
        "psr-0": { "": "src/" }
    },
    "require": {
        "php": ">=5.3.3",
        "symfony/symfony": "~2.4",
        "doctrine/orm": "~2.2,>=2.2.3",
        "doctrine/doctrine-bundle": "~1.2",
        "twig/extensions": "~1.0",
        "symfony/assetic-bundle": "~2.3",
        "symfony/swiftmailer-bundle": "~2.3",
        "symfony/monolog-bundle": "~2.4",
        "sensio/distribution-bundle": "~2.3",
        "sensio/framework-extra-bundle": "~3.0",
        "sensio/generator-bundle": "~2.3",
        "incenteev/composer-parameter-handler": "~2.0",
"sylius/product-bundle":"1.0.*@dev"
    },
"minimum-stability": "dev",
    "scripts": {
        "post-install-cmd": [
            "Incenteev\\ParameterHandler\\ScriptHandler::buildParameters",
            "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::buildBootstrap",
            "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::clearCache",
            "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::installAssets",
            "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::installRequirementsFile"
        ],
        "post-update-cmd": [
            "Incenteev\\ParameterHandler\\ScriptHandler::buildParameters",
            "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::buildBootstrap",
            "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::clearCache",
            "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::installAssets",
            "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::installRequirementsFile"
        ]
    },
    "config": {
        "bin-dir": "bin"
    },
    "extra": {
        "symfony-app-dir": "app",
        "symfony-web-dir": "web",
        "incenteev-parameters": {
            "file": "app/config/parameters.yml"
        },
        "branch-alias": {
            "dev-master": "2.4-dev"
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Instead of lowering the minimum stability for the whole project, it's better to add all the unstable packages with the `@dev` suffix.

Answer (score 0):

Would there be a problem if I just updated my doctrine-bundle to ~1.3.

After I did this I ran a composer update. And then did a require sylius product bundle. Worked alright!